# c++ Build class attributes from configuration file

Tags: c++

I've already implemented an algorithm using a class with hard coded attributes.

But now, I'd like add some flexibility to it.

Suppose that I've used only two attributes of the four available for `class Voice`.  By available, I mean that I have data for them, stored in a database.

```
class Voice
{
    double price;                  // used this one.
    unsigned int duration;         // and this one.
    string destination;
    string operatorid;
}
```

I created a vector such that vector[0][0] = price of first element, vector[0][1] = duration of 1st element, and so on.

I'd like a user to edit a config file (I've been using [SimpleIni.h](http://code.jellycan.com/simpleini-doc/html/index.html)), and add the attributes he wants, preferable in the order he desires, like for example:

```
[Voice]
attribute1 = operatorid
attribute2 = price
attribute3 = duration
```

`Voice` should than be built with these three attributes only so that vector[n] would have `vector[n][0]` = value of operatorid for `nth` element, `vector[n][1]` = value of price for `nth` element, `vector[n][2]` = value of duration for `nth` element.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: AFAIK `operator` is a reserved keyword in C++, maybe you should use another one.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Voice should than be built with these three attributes only"*?

Comment: @Constantinius: you're right, I was just building that as an example, I'll change that.

Comment: @Constantinius: At a time, the user may only want to run the algorithm with three attributes, at other time with two, or four, or eigh or whatever.  Maybe this is not possible, nor desirable, maybe there is another simple solution for my problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use the `class Voice`, I guess just using a couple of vectors for your input data should be better suited... e.g: `vector<double> prices; vector<unsigned int> durations; ...`

Comment: shouldn't the user specify the values for those attributes too?

Comment: I don't know how vectors fit in. I can understand a design which builds Voice objects which are stored a vector, but could you explain how you are storing (why you are storing) attributes in class Voice and a vector for each attribute.

Comment: you shouldn't call your vector `vector`.

Comment: @jnbbender it's the difference between an array of structs and a struct of arrays. You are describing an array of struct (vector<Voice>) whereas Constantinius describes a loose collection of attributes, not necessarily classified under Voice.

Comment: you can always generate code and compile on the fly :)

Comment: This question is too vague.  Of course it is possible to load data from a file.  What did you try and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

This reminded me of Python (just a bit):

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/get.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

class Foo
{
  typedef boost::variant<double, int, std::string> var;

  struct NoSuchAttributeError {
    NoSuchAttributeError(const std::string &key) {
      std::cout << boost::format("Attribute %s not found!\n") % key; 
    }
  };

  std::map<std::string, var> attributes;

  var& getattr(const std::string& key) {
    std::map<std::string, var>::iterator it = attributes.find(key);
    if (it == attributes.end()) {
      throw NoSuchAttributeError(key);
    }
    else {
      return (*it).second;
    }
  }

  template<typename T> 
  T& get(var& v) {
    return boost::get<T, double, int, std::string>(v);
  }

public:
  Foo() {
    // TODO: add attributes according to configuration file
    attributes["foo"] = 42;
    attributes["bar"] = "baz";
  }

  // TODO: add appropriate getters/setters for attributes
  int& foo() { return get<int>(attributes["foo"]); }
  std::string& bar() { return get<std::string>(attributes["bar"]); }
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  std::cout << f.foo() << " " << f.bar() << std::endl;
  f.foo() = 13;
  f.bar() = "Hello World!";
  std::cout << f.foo() << " " << f.bar() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```